# Error with install opencv 3 on OS X

Tags: qt, homebrew, opencv3.0

the problem is installation of opencv with brew has crashed with errors:

> Command: brew install opencv3 --HEAD  --with-contrib --with-cuda --with-ffmpeg --with-tbb --with-qt5

[image]

Comment: What's your problem? What are you trying to achieve? [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: @JoeyCiechanowicz ok, I changed question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in old version libraries such as libpng and libtiff.

Answer (score 0):

please download opencv-3.x.x form git hub and then install its work.